# Rails: Manipulate rendered JSON when using UJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, ujs

I enhanced my app by allowing AJAX form submissions, using UJS. Here is my create#product action:

```
def create

    if Product.create params[:product]
        respond_to do |format|

            message = "New product created."
            format.html { redirect_to :back, :notice => message }
            format.js { render :json => { :status => true, :message => message } }

        end
    end

end
```

But I'm figuring out how to handle outputted JSON in my `views/products/create.js.erb` file??

I tried this simple console.log example, but without success (I mean, no console output):

```
$(function(){
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
$('form.new_product').bind('ajax:success',function(event, data, status, xhr){

});

$('form.new_product').bind('ajax:error',function(event, xhr, status, error){

});
```

or even `$('form.new_product').on(same_args)`.

Just make sure `new_product` is the actual class of your form.

Comment: Thanks a lot apneadiving. Indeed, I forgotted to bing AJAX events.